# Can't close a program via .BAT after printing PDF document

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, scheduled-tasks

I need to print copies of PDF document with a delay before printing each copy. I created a new task in the Windows' Task Scheduler and in the Actions tab of the Scheduler I selected my BAT file with the following code:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" /t D:\myfilename.pdf "HP" "hp psc 1300 series" USB001
```

When I run the task, empty FoxitReader window and the command promt window are being opened and my PDF document is being successfully printed.

The problem is both windows are not being closed programatically after printing and the next copy is not being printed until I manually closed the FoxitReader window (the command promt is being closed at the same time).

Yes, I remember that I print with a delay before each copy and my delay is just 1 minute. But the next copy is not being printed even after a few minutes without manual closing the windows.

I tried to add to my BAT file the line

```
taskkill /IM FoxitReader.exe
```

and

```
taskkill /IM FoxitReader.exe /F
```

but still the windows are not being closed and I don't see the `taskkill` line in the command promt window when the window is opened.

If I create another BAT file with the `taskkill` line and run it, the FoxitReader process is being ended. So I even tried to call separate BAT file by adding to my first BAT file the line

```
call "END.bat"
```

but the problem is still not resolved

I use Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

This is a documented bug in FoxIt Reader.  See it here:
http://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-reader/156463-printing-with-foxit-reader-using-command-line-command
and here:
http://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-reader/149617-print-pdf-via-command-line-and-exit-foxit-reader

They do claim that [FoxIt Reader 6.2](http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/reader/desktop/win/6.x/6.2/enu/FoxitReader623.815_enu_Setup.exe) works, if you're up to trying that.
Otherwise, there's http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/pdftoprinter.html and other options.  (Check "print pdf from windows command line" in your favorite Web browser.)

Sorry for the bad news, but hopefully something in this helps lessen the pain going forward.

EDIT: I just had another idea.  Try wmic's TERMINATE method.  I think one of these should work to kill your foxit processes:

wmic /interactive:off process where name="FoxitReader.exe" call terminate

or

wmic /interactive:off process where name="FoxitReader.exe" delete

You may have to run it under elevated privileges.  Good luck!